# Intent android youtube player app in full-screen mode

Tags: android, youtube, android-intent, fullscreen

Could we make an intent for youtube player app in portrait(full-screen-horizontal) mode. I want "my android app users" to open youtube video in full screen? How can I prevent my users from seeing the youtube videos' details, comments, view number, etc by letting them only the portrait view(full screen)? Even if they use the android phone vertically, how can I let them only horizontal-full screen view of youtube player thereby forcing them to turn their phone. ?

Comment: I don't think you can. As soon as you open the Youtube is not your code running and unless Google guys have added that kind support to the app, I am not seeing it happening.

Answer (score 2):

As for YouTube v4.1.47, you can do the following:

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
playIntent.setData(Uri.parse(<yout_YouTube_url>));
playIntent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
```

It might work on older versions, but I haven't tested it.