# How to hide status bar for applications launched from custom home screen

Tags: android

How **www.kytephone.com** Parent control application manages to hide the Android status bar under their custom status bar. They do it for most applications launched from their home application.

I know that status bar can be hiden in my application by

`setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

But how do they do it for **other applications** ?I am googling last few hours but not get solution.please give me guideline.

Edit:
Maybe I am wrong and they somehow split screen and launch the apps in the bottom part and show the custom status bar on the top. Is it possible?

Comment: @Harshid you are right about few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking, but I think these might help shed some light on your question:

[How to set the application to fullscreen from an Intent, Not from the main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275352/how-to-set-the-application-to-fullscreen-from-an-intent-not-from-the-main-activ)

[Intent android youtube player app in full-screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306396/intent-android-youtube-player-app-in-full-screen-mode)

It seems like when you're launching an application from your app, you need to send information with the Intent that you're launching. **Though it's also possible that these are app specific;** being able to alter settings in an app or activity that you're launching that you do not have access to posses a security risk.

Hope that helps.